# How to make a new data frame automatically from variables of another data frame in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, automatic-updates

I have a data table with 3 variables (It is just an example):

```
DT <- data.table (A=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5), B=c(200,210,300,420,289,365,587,250,110,500,800), C=c(0.6,0.35,0.6,0.85,0.22,0.36,0.39,0.31,0.33,0.58,0.66))
```

I have split `DT` based on `A`

```
DT_Split <- split(DT, DT$A)
```

So, the output is:

```
$`1`
   A   B    C
1: 1 200 0.60
2: 1 210 0.35
3: 1 300 0.60

$`2`
   A   B    C
1: 2 420 0.85
2: 2 289 0.22

$`3`
   A   B    C
1: 3 365 0.36
2: 3 587 0.39

$`4`
   A   B    C
1: 4 250 0.31
2: 4 110 0.33
3: 4 500 0.58

$`5`
   A   B    C
1: 5 800 0.66
```

I can make new data tables from every data table that I have in `DT_Split`:

```
A<- DT_Split$`1`
B<- DT_Split$`2`
C<- DT_Split$`3`
D<- DT_Split$`4`
E<- DT_Split$`5`
```

But my question is:
Is it possible to do this automatically?
Is it possible to make new data tables with defined names for every data table in `DT_Split` automatically instead of doing `[A<- DT_Split$1 ... E<- DT_Split$5]` ?

I would appreciate if you could give me some idea.
Thanks

Comment: You can first name the list `names(DT_Split) <- c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E')` and then use `list2env(DT_Split, .GlobalEnv)`

Comment: Thank you so much, Ronak! That's great!